# Google Sheets - Using INDIRECT (or alternative) within a query

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently using this formula:

`=SORT(QUERY(G:Z, "select K,count(K) where K is not null group by K label count(K)''"),2,TRUE)`

I have to replace all instances of "K" with a column letter that is written in cell B2, so I can quickly change the entire formula by simply entering the letter in the cell.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
=SORT(QUERY(E:K, "select " & D1 &" ,count(" & D1 &") where " & D1 &" is not null group by " & D1 &" label count(" & D1 &")''"),2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you!

Comment: Follow up question. Current formula has count in column B, can I get a percent in column C (Like this: =B3/SUM(B$3:B)), but as part of the query formula?

Answer (score 0):

as already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70276997/5632629) use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(1,      MATCH(B1, CHAR(ROW(A65:A99)), 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(100000, MATCH(B1, CHAR(ROW(A65:A99)), 0), 4))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ro0ek6YHeHhfS89zPsC60RywDFtScUGlttoZmYT_9fg/copy)